# Yii2 elastic search help required

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions, elasticsearch-plugin

Can any one provide the best example of how to use Yii2 Elastic extension?

I'm having error any one know about this please let me know.

> Elasticsearch Database Exception – yii\elasticsearch\Exception Cluster
>   autodetection did not find any active node.

```
'elasticsearch' => [
        'class' => 'yii\elasticsearch\Connection',
        'nodes' => [
            ['http_address' => '127.0.0.1:80/mapping-index'],
            // configure more hosts if you have a cluster
        ],
    ],
```

Thanks.

Comment: "did not find any active node" - i assume that elastic search is running with at least on active node. or not ?

Comment: I've know idea, I am using it for the first time. Can you please provide me the simple example to use search in Yii2

Comment: I believe you need to download elastic search and make sure it's running locally. Most probably your plugin is not able to locate a node cause you don't have elastic search running locally or on any other host.

Comment: I've installed the extension from composer and added code in config  common/config/main-local.php  and code  you can find above.

Comment: Please confirm you have dowloaded, installed, and started Elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/running-elasticsearch.html. This step has nothing to do with Yii or PHP.